# How can I combine 2 validators together in play2?

Tags: forms, validation, scala, playframework-2.0

For example, I want a input should be `nonEmptyText` and `email`.

If the user doesn't input anything, it will show error message `The field is required`, if user inputs an invalid email, it will show `Invalid email`.

But I found, I can just use one:

```
val loginForm = Form("email"->nonEmptyText)
```

or:

```
val loginForm = Form("email"->email)
```

For the later one, if user doesn't input, it will still show `Invalid email`, which is not what I want.

**UPDATE1**

I tried [Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740444/342235):

```
val loginForm = Form("email" -> (email verifying nonEmpty))
```

When user inputs nothing, the error message will be:

```
Valid email required, This field is required
```

Looks like play combines two error messages of `email` and `nonEmpty` together, but this is not exactly what I want. I hope when user not input, the message is only:

```
This field is required
```

Not:

```
Valid email required, This field is required
```

**UPDATE2**

I found the reason why it display combined errors is in the `helper.twitterBootstrapFieldConstructor.scala.html`, there is:

```
<span class="help-inline">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(",")</span>
```

It combines all the errors with `,`.

For my case, it should be:

```
<span class="help-inline">@elements.errors(elements.lang).lastOption</span>
```

Here, `lastOption` is for `nonEmpty`.

But I think `headOption` is better, but:

```
val loginForm = Form("email" -> (nonEmptyText verifying email))
```

Doesn't work -- there is no constraint of `email`, so we have to defined one for myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Form documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms), you can add constraints to a mapping using the `verifying` method. There are a few constraints already defined in the [`Constraints` object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.data.validation.Constraints%24). So you can write:

```scala
val loginForm = Form("email" -> (email verifying nonEmpty))
```

Comment: Thanks! `email verifying nonEmpty` should be wrapped in `()`, right?

Comment: The second problem is (IMHO) a bug in the current Play 2.0, see [this issue](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/249-the-email-mapping-should-not-raise-a-validation-error-when-the-value-is-empty#ticket-249-1).
You’re right for the `()`